# Creating Folder using Java in lotus notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

hi I am trying to create a folder using java in Louts notes.I have created an agent in Domino Designer.I have created a document and i am setting the following properties of the document.
Here is the code.

```
    doc.replaceItemValue("$ColumnFormatItem", "$Sender1");
    doc.replaceItemValue("$ColumnFormatExtItem", "$Sender1");
    doc.replaceItemValue("$ColumnProfileDoc", "ColorProfile");
    doc.replaceItemValue("$DesignerVersion", "8.5.3");
    doc.replaceItemValue("$FormulaClass", "1");
    doc.replaceItemValue("$Name", "SmithsFolder");
    doc.replaceItemValue("$PublicAccess", "1");
    doc.replaceItemValue("$ThreadView", "$ThreadsEmbed");

    doc.replaceItemValue("$Title", "SmithsFolder");
    doc.replaceItemValue("$ViewInheritedFrom","($Inbox)");
    doc.replaceItemValue("$BrowserRender", "Body");
    doc.replaceItemValue("$WebFlags", "S");
    doc.replaceItemValue("Form", "Memo");
    doc.replaceItemValue("Importance", "2");
    doc.replaceItemValue("NamePreference", "0");
    doc.replaceItemValue("priority_tcs", "Internal");
    doc.replaceItemValue("useApplet", "True");
    doc.replaceItemValue("ConfidentialString", "Confidential");
    doc.replaceItemValue("DefaultMailSaveOption", "1");
    doc.replaceItemValue("DisplayFrom", "");
    doc.replaceItemValue("ExpandPersonalGroups", "1");
    doc.replaceItemValue("NamePreference", "0");
```

And after this i am saving the document.but i cannot see any folder getting created.Please help.

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to achieve. A folder and a document in Notes/Domino is two different things. In your code example you are adding items to a document but you are not doing anything related to a folder.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..i am trying to add a new folder.If my approach itself is wrong please guide me in the correct direction.

Comment: Take a look at enableFolder: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc%2FH_ENABLEFOLDER_METHOD_JAVA.html

Comment: thanks bro..it indeed solved the problem.i am able to create folder with EnableFolder method.

Comment: Great to hear. I've added an answer

Comment: can u please tell how to rename a folder that is created from the user

Comment: Use setName on the view object (which you can use for folders too): http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NAME_PROPERTY_VIEW_JAVA.html

Comment: FYI, although you didn't show how you created the document in the above code, I'm guessing you were trying to go low level but you used the standard NotesDatabase.CreateDocument method. If that's true, then the reason that your approach didn't work is that although a document and a folder are both represented internally in the NSF file as a Note, they have different Note Classes. The CreateDocument method always creates a Note with NOTE_CLASS_DOCUMENT, but the folder must have NOTE_CLASS_VIEW. The APIs in Java (and LotusScript) don't include a direct method for setting/changing the Note Class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the enableFolder method in order to create a folder:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc%2FH_ENABLEFOLDER_METHOD_JAVA.html