# Folder created using Java is not visible in Lotus Notes

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

based on the answer[Creating Folders in lotus notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21135476/creating-folder-using-java-in-lotus-notes) i have created folder in lotus notes.When i tested it locally it is working fine.when the same code is deployed in the server.i cannot see any folder created.But i am getting the UniversalId fo the folder created.Please help.Below is the code i am using.thanks in advance.

```
m_session = getSession();
dbdir = m_session.getDbDirectory("");
m_database = dbdir.openMailDatabase();
m_database.enableFolder("newFolder");
view=m_database.getView("newFolder");
view.getUniversalId();
view.setDefaultView(true);
```

Comment: hey i found that the folders are getting created in admin notes instead of users mail file. please help how to fix this.i mean how to make the folders getting created in the users mail file.

Answer (score 0):

if you use the dbDirectory to open the maildatabase whatever contacts we add and whatever folders we create is going to be created in admin notes.Instead we should be opening the mail database directly from the session as shown below.

```
m_session = getSession();
m_database = m_session.openMailDatabase();
```

it was the below extra line of code that was causing the problem.

```
dbdir = m_session.getDbDirectory("");
```